# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level tutorials

Tags: python, django

This is the output I got:

[image: This is the output]

I lerned how to do that here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/

My code is:

```
def index(request):
   latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
   template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
   context = {
    '   latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
   }
   # output = ', '.join([q.question_text for q in latest_question_list])
   return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

And this is the error raised:

```
 File "C:\Users\ab\mysite\polls\views.py", line 9
   context = {
          ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just remove white spaces from `'   latest_question_list': latest_question_list,` ....

Comment: thanks for such a frequent reply but its not working

Comment: Take a deep look at your indentation, mixing whitespaces and tabs e.g.?

Comment: rocksteady must be right

Comment: my indentations are correct but still the error is keep on rising

Comment: Try removing all of the indentations at the start of each line, and then put them back in using all tabs or all spaces, as rocksteady was talking about, if they become mixed up, it will give you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-tt` option when you run Python. This will give you an error if you mix tabs and spaces.